# I have a circle with $n$ equal tangent circles inscribed, what is the diameter of the largest circles that could be inscribed in the space left?

Tags: geometry, circles

Hello I know that the question is very long and maybe confused, I'll do my best to explain it step by step.

The problem is relevant in the cable design industry. The first step is to define the diameter of a circle and its numerosity *n*: from that I calculate the diameter of a *supercicle* that contains *n* tangent circles. To calculate that I cheated a little bit: I used a factor called "lay up factor" (that factor it's defined in an international ISO norm), so for instance if I have $3$ circles of diameter *d* the diameter *s* of the *supercircle* will be $2.13*d$. After that I have to calculate the diameter of the largest circle that can be inscribed between the *supercircle* and the base circles.

Maybe some images will make the problem clearer.

My final goal is to calculate the diameter of the red circles:

[image: Final goal]

First step is to put *n* circles of diameter *d* tangent to each other:

[image: Base tangent circles]

I draw the *supercicle* (yellow) and calculate its diameter *s*:

[image: Base circles and supercircle]

It would be nice to understand how to calculate the red circles diameter for any numerosity, but I'm interested in the case of $3$ (so $3$ base circles).

Comment: It is helpful to others if you can inline the images in your question instead of making them clickable links. You can just do a copy image and paste into the question/answer box and follow the prompts to inline the image.

Comment: @vvg My recollection (possibly wrong) is that stackexchange makes it more difficult for newcomers to do that. I have inlined the images.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, I didn't know how to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $3$ mutually tangent base circles of radius $r$, their centers will form an equilateral triangle with side length $2r$.  So the distance between the center of each of the three circles and the center of this equilateral triangle is

$ d = \dfrac{2}{3} \bigg( \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} (2 r) \bigg) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} r $

The radius of the big circle is just

$ R = d + r = \bigg(1 + \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \bigg) r $

Now using Descartes' kissing circles theorem, the radius of the red circles is

$u$ and satisfies,

$ \dfrac{1}{u} = \dfrac{1}{r} + \dfrac{1}{r} - \dfrac{1}{R} + 2 \sqrt{ \dfrac{1}{r^2} - \dfrac{1}{r R} - \dfrac{1 }{rR} } $

$ \dfrac{1}{u} = \bigg(\dfrac{1}{r}\bigg) \bigg( 2 - \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{ \sqrt{3} +2 } + 2 \sqrt{ \dfrac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{2 +  \sqrt{3} } } \bigg) $

Decimally, this evaluates to

$ \dfrac{1}{u} = \dfrac{2.07179677}{r} $

From which,

$ u = \dfrac{r}{2.07179677} = 0.482673 r $

Comment: As far as I understood, having $R$, I could calculate *u* for any *n* (being *n* the numerosity of base circles), because in that configuration there are always four kissing circles, right?

Comment: Yes.  That's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put the diagram on the coordinate plane, with the supercircle centered at the origin, and the $+x$-axis going through the tangent point of two blue circles and the center of one red circle. Call $S$ the radius of the supercircle, $R$ the radius of the blue circles, and $r$ the radius of the red circle.

All the blue circles have centers on a circle around the origin with radius $S-R$. So the two blue circles touching the $+x$-axis have centers at $((S-R) \cos \frac{\pi}{n}, \pm (S-R) \sin \frac{\pi}{n})$. But the distance of either center from the $x$-axis is also $R$, so if $n \geq 3$,

$$ (S-R) \sin \frac{\pi}{n} = R $$
$$ R = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}{1+\sin \frac{\pi}{n}} S $$
$$ S = R\left(1+\csc \frac{\pi}{n}\right) $$

And we can rewrite the centers of the two blue circles touching the $+x$-axis as $(R \cot \frac{\pi}{n}, \pm R)$.

The center of the red circle on the $+x$-axis is $(S-r,0)$. The distance between the center of this red circle and the center of a tangent blue circle must be $R+r$:

$$ \sqrt{\left(S-r- R \cot \frac{\pi}{n}\right)^2 + R^2} = R+r $$
$$ \left(R + R \csc \frac{\pi}{n} - R \cot \frac{\pi}{n} - r\right)^2 + R^2 = R^2+2Rr+r^2 $$
$$ \left(R + R \tan \frac{\pi}{2n} -r\right)^2 = 2Rr + r^2 $$
$$ R^2 \left(1+ \tan \frac{\pi}{2n}\right)^2 - 2Rr \left(1+\tan\frac{\pi}{2n}\right) + r^2 = 2Rr + r^2 $$
$$ R^2 \left(1+\tan \frac{\pi}{2n}\right)^2 = 2Rr \left(2+\tan\frac{\pi}{2n}\right) $$
$$ R \left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2n} + \sin\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)^2 = 2r \left(2\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{2n} + \cos\frac{\pi}{2n} \sin\frac{\pi}{2n}\right) $$
$$ R \left(\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{2n}+2\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}\sin\frac{\pi}{2n} + \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2n}\right) = 2r\left(1+\cos \frac{\pi}{n}+\frac{1}{2} \sin \frac{\pi}{n}\right) $$
$$ R \left(1+\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\right) = r\left(2+2\cos \frac{\pi}{n}+\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\right) $$
$$ r = \frac{1+\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}{2+2\cos\frac{\pi}{n}+\sin\frac{\pi}{n}} R $$

$$ r = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}{2+2\cos\frac{\pi}{n}+\sin\frac{\pi}{n}} S $$

For $n=3$, we have $\frac{S}{R} = 1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \approx 2.155$, $\frac{r}{R} = 2-\sqrt{3} \approx 0.4827$, and $\frac{r}{S} = \frac{1}{1+2\sqrt{3}} \approx 0.2240$. The result for $\frac{S}{R}$ is a bit larger than your quoted $2.13$; I'm not sure why. The result for $\frac{r}{R}$ in my notation matches the result for $\frac{u}{r}$ in the notation of @Nathalieissweetandawesome's answer.

Comment: Let me add some content to clarify why - in my opinion - you got $2.2240$ while I used $2.13$. The blue and red circle are actually insulated conductor i.e. copper core with a layer of plastic compound. They are put in the set up shown in the figure and then laid up that means they are twisted together tightly. Of course the plastic layer will compress a little bit, so I guess that the ISO norm recognizes that and give a value a little bit smaller than the geometric solution.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. (The comparison is $2.155$ vs. $2.13$.) I thought it might have to do with physical engineering reality, but only thought of adding a little space in between, which would increase, not decrease, that ratio. Squeezing the "blue" wires a little does make sense out of that. Though that might tend to push them out toward the "red" wires. Maybe the "red" wires also compress to push back against the blue... I'm not sure how it would work out. But with about a 1% shrink from compression without the red, probably around 1% total is still the ballpark result.